# Connecting inventory from SquareSpace to WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, squarespace, inventory

I currently need advice on how to link the inventory from a SquareSpace website to show up on a WordPress website. The SquareSpace website has inventory but low traffic to the website, and the WordPress website has no inventory but high traffic. These are 2 rare coin businesses that are trying to work together via promoting the inventory from the SquareSpace website on the WordPress website. It would be ideal to have them synced up so anytime someone purchases inventory from the SquareSpace website, it would update the inventory on the WordPress website.

Goal: Display the inventory that is on [this website](https://raregoldcoins.com/rare-gold-coin-inventory) (made with SquareSpace)  to show up on [this website](https://www.coinfully.com/) (made with WordPress). Would like the inventory to be synced up to real-time, so that when an item is added or purchased, it automatically updates. Would also prefer if when a user clicks on the inventory displayed on the WordPress website, they are redirected to the SquareSpace website (where the inventory originates).

I've tried downloading the inventory on an XML file and importing it over to the WordPress website - does not automatically update to changes made on the SquareSpace website.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there isn't a product that exists which updates content from one CMS to another.

Depending on your WordPress theme, you could opt for the query route. This would involve creating the products on the WordPress site and determining what to display by querying information from the SquareSpace site, such as coin names. In theory, this should work with custom code in WordPress.

To provide a smoother process, I would create custom code that downloads the SquareSpace product list as an XML file onto the WordPress server for querying every 12 hours.